# make node.js fs.readFile as promised action using Q

Tags: node.js, promise, q

when I use `deferred.resolve` way to promise a action,I can't get the content of the file

```
function readFile(fileName) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', deferred.resolve);
    return deferred.promise;
};

readFile('test.txt').then(function (err, data) {
    console.log('data:' + data)
})
```

I get `data:undefined` output

but it works OK fine when I promised action `httpGet`

```
var httpGet = function (opts) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    http.get(opts, deferred.resolve);
    return deferred.promise;
};

httpGet('http://www.google.com').then(function (res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
        })
    }
);
```

Is there something wrong the code above and in this way how can i get the content of the file.
or is there something different between fs.readFile and http.get?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Q.nfcall` to call a NodeJS function promisified.

```
function httpGet(opts){
    return Q.nfcall(http.get,opts);
}
```

Or simply:

```
var httpGet = Q.nfbind(http.get,http)
```

This would also work for `fs.readFile` by the way.

If you want to do it manually. Q's deferred objects have a `.makeNodeResolver` function which lets you pass them around safely like you do:

```
var httpGet = function (opts) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    http.get(opts, deferred.makeNodeResolver());
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

One of the things `.makeNodeResolver` does is bind the `.this` value.

It is better to use `.nfcall` though.

Comment: It is worth mentioning other libraries like Bluebird are orders of magnitude faster here as they use techniques like dynamic recompilation to create a promisified function that is (almost) as fast as the callback version.